# Is there a good way to identify a word, even if it's misspelled in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of words (mostly locations, like Stockholm and London) and a bunch of strings. like "I want to go from stockholm to london". I want to find out what words are in what strings.

I currently use .indexOf to perform this task.

Is there a library, method, function etc, in javascript that identifies misspelled versions of words?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme

Check out the `levenshtein _.levenshtein(string1, string2)` distance function. It can be used to calculate the distance between too strings.

Answer (score 2):

I found this JS library http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/ that is supposed to check spelling in several languages

Answer (score 2):

After reading the above I'm not sure if I'm exactly clear on what you are trying to do... but regarding your final question about identifying words which are incorrectly spelled -- I'd take a look at [java script spell check](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/).  And as a side note.. Often people try and use [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) when they want to count words which are spelled both correctly and incorrectly.

Comment: whoops!  looks like davidaam beat me to javascriptspellcheck while I was posting.  I'd delete but I wanted to leave in the bit about soundex.

Answer (score 0):

php by default has levenshtein function. you can use this method by using [PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/) library.

by finding the levenshtein distance between the word and a dictionary of correct words you can obtain a word with least levenshtein distance from the miss-spelled word. This would most probably be the correct spelling for a particular word.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used [MissPlete](https://github.com/xavi/miss-plete) library, which uses [Jaro–Winkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) distance algoritm by default.

It has no dependencies (not even jQuery), which I highly value.